# Fail to start Mariadb server (code=killed)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, debian

I have a problem with my mariadb server on debian : it used to work, but not anymore. When I try to start it, I have this error :

```
-- L'unité (unit) mariadb.service a commencé à démarrer.
juin 28 16:05:30 p2node-g1-petitecolo mysqld[665649]: 2020-06-28 16:05:30 140370356227456 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.41-MariaDB-0+deb9u1) starting as process 665649 ...
juin 28 16:05:31 p2node-g1-petitecolo systemd[1]: Started MariaDB 10.1.41 database server.
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) mariadb.service a terminé son démarrage
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) mariadb.service a terminé son démarrage, avec le résultat done.
juin 28 19:05:23 p2node-g1-petitecolo systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
juin 28 19:05:23 p2node-g1-petitecolo systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
juin 28 19:05:23 p2node-g1-petitecolo systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
juin 28 19:05:28 p2node-g1-petitecolo systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
juin 28 19:05:28 p2node-g1-petitecolo systemd[1]: Stopped MariaDB 10.1.41 database server.
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) mariadb.service a terminé son arrêt
```

And

```
> sudo service mysql status
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.1.41 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: signal) since Mon 2020-07-06 09:37:26 CEST; 4s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 991549 ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 991545 ExecStartPost=/etc/mysql/debian-start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2379279 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=killed, signal=KILL)
  Process: 2379204 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=ex
  Process: 2379202 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2379201 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2379279 (code=killed, signal=KILL)
```

Any idea of why I have a `code=killed` ??

Thanks for your help !

Comment: you must look with `journalctl -xe` it is written there what is happening. here is not the info. Please go with this Question to Serverfault